# Is there a better way to search a column with a column and copy the offset to another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to Search Column Y Sheet2 with Column X Sheet1.values
when a match is found the value from the next column over Sheet2(z) is copied to Sheet 1 Column Y

As you can see I ain't the best at coding.

Standard excel.

```
  Sub searchingit()

  Dim rowNum As Integer
  Dim countOf As Integer
  DO
  DoEvents
  rowNum = rowNum + 1
  dudetoFind = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X" & rowNum).Value
  wheretoFind = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Y:Y").Value

  If dudetoFind.Value = wheretoFind.Value Then

  wheretoFind.Offset(0, 1).Copy
  wheretoFind = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Y" + rowNum)
  countOf = countOf + 1
  End If

  Loop Until countOf = 2911


  End Sub
```

Compare two column. When a match is found the offset next column value is copied bask to the original sheet to an empty column X.

Comment: Why not a formula: `=IF(Sheet1!X:X=Sheet2!Y:Y,Sheet2!Z:Z,"")`? Actually your code doesn't look like it will work. Does it run at all? • Please include screenshots or example data to reproduce it and too see how your expected result would look like.

Answer (score 0):

VBA Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim position As Range, cell As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim LastRow1 As Long, Lastrow2 As Long

    With ThisWorkbook

        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")

    End With

    LastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
    Lastrow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 24), ws1.Cells(LastRow1, 24))
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, 25), ws2.Cells(Lastrow2, 25))

    For Each cell In rng1

        Set position = rng2.Find(cell, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If position Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "Name was not found."
        Else
            ws1.Range("Y" & cell.Row).Value = ws2.Range("Z" & position.Row).Value
        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```